# Pass parameter when creating new Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that is showing details of my post with comments, it also rendering a partial view that is responsible for comment adding. The problem is that I don't know how to pass parameter with `new Comment()` with already existing value in it. That is `PostID`.

`model` is Post model that is being used for rendering post data like Body/Title etc...
My code: `@Html.Partial("_CommentAdd", new Comment())` 
What I want to do: `@Html.Partial("_CommentAdd", new Comment({ PostID = model.ID}))`

Full Code

```
@using project01.Models
@model project01.Models.Post
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Title</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Body</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Body)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Tags</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tags)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Date</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
</fieldset>

@Html.Partial("_CommentAdd", new Comment())

@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Comment", comment)
}
```

Picture with arrow that is showing what I want to achieve.
[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your syntax just a bit off? Try this (the property intializers go after the constructor, not as "arguments" to the constructor call):

```
@Html.Partial("_CommentAdd", new Comment() { PostID = model.ID })
```

Comment: Yes, it is a bit off since it was more of a pseudo code, I didn't know the right Syntax, new to this. Thanks man, this worked great!

Comment: Glad it helped. This syntax can be used anywhere when creating new objects in C# 3. I find it to be a great convenience.